# How to display text / button at the end of tabs component using Bootstrap?

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I've added a text and a button inside `<ul>` tag like this:

```
<body>
   <div class="container">
    <ul class="nav nav-tabs" role="tablist">
       <li role="presentation" class="active"><a href="#">Database</a></li>
       <li role="presentation"><a href="#">Tasks</a></li>
       <li role="presentation"><a href="#">Options</a></li>
       <li role="presentation">Welcome, ${sessionScope.currentUser} <button type="submit" >Log out</button></li>
   </ul>
  </div>
 </body>
```

And the result is:

[image]

If I wrap the text and the button inside `<a>` tag then the bottom line is pushed too far away. You can see there is a line at the bottom of "Database" tab.

I want the text and the button move to the end of the tabs component like the tabs of this forum. The text "2 Answers" has the same height with the tab "votes" and is in the edge of the tabs pane:

[image]

I know that I have to modify it with JavaScript, but I don't know how to do it.

Comment: what exactly do you want?  just the welsome text and button to be aligned vertically in the center?  or do you want the text and button all the way to the left like the second image.  Also always please try to provide code , in your case the styling

Comment: I want them move to the right, at the end of the pane. The second image is just a description, I don't them all the way to the left.

Comment: on the last li element, set " text-align:right " attribute. if the li domains the rest of the space, it will work.

Comment: hina10531: it doesn't work, and I think the last li domains a small space.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I am understanding you correctly , you just would like the last 2 `<li>` elements all the way to the right , and the remaining ones to stay all the way to the left.  To accomplish set the style of the last 2 `<li>` elements to `"float:right"`

replace this HTML with the existing HTML :

```
<body>
   <div class="container">
    <ul class="nav nav-tabs" role="tablist">
       <li role="presentation" class="active"><a href="#">Database</a></li>
       <li role="presentation"><a href="#">Tasks</a></li>
       <li role="presentation" style="float:right;"><a href="#">Options</a></li>
       <li role="presentation"  style="float:right;line-height:45px;">Welcome, ${sessionScope.currentUser}<button type="submit" >Log out</button></li>
   </ul>
  </div>
 </body>`
```

UPDATED CODE , There are many ways to vertically align text, you can use `vertical-align` , `line-height` , `padding`'s , and `margin`'s.   I adjusted the `line-height` to set the text in the middle

Comment: Thank you, Selby. It works. You understand me right, except the tab "Options". For the second intention, how to align vertical them in the center ? I know I can do it with a thinner button, but I would like to know about your solution.

Comment: Sorry about I can't upvote for you because I don't have enough reputation. line-height:45px is tall, so the bottom line is pushed away again.

Comment: you can use  margin-top:8px;    now that you see how to do it you have to play around .   Come here to be pushed in the right direction , but not to have everything completed for you.   Just try 40px , or 38px ,   or play around with margin-top: 10px or 15px

Answer (score 6):

Here's the answer and the result for you.

You can check it out here http://jsfiddle.net/vyy3zszj/

Or just take below

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<style type="text/css">

  li.rightside { 
    float:right; 
    line-height:34px;
  }
  
</style>

   <div class="container">
    <ul class="nav nav-tabs" role="tablist">
       <li role="presentation" class="active"><a href="#">Database</a></li>
       <li role="presentation"><a href="#">Tasks</a></li>
       <li role="presentation"><a href="#">Options</a></li>
       <li class="rightside" role="presentation">Welcome, CurrentUser <button type="submit" >Log out</button></li>
   </ul>
  </div>
```

Somehow the defined css in this code snippet doesn't work. So I inserted  above the body. FYI, you can use inline style for sure.

Comment: Thanks, it works for me. But the button is bigger, I will modify it.

Comment: Then just add this style on the button, " line-height: initial " , which means it will not inherit the parent element's line-height value.